# NDSolve ignores my NeumannValue boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve a simple linear differential equation for $f(x,y)$ on a square with area $L\times L =1$.

I consider
$(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)f + \partial_x \partial_y f = 0$ with the following boundary conditions:
$\partial_x f(0,y) = 1$, $\partial_y f(x,0) = 0$, $\partial_y f(x,1) = 0$, $f(1,y) = 0$.

To solve this differential equation, I have used the NDSolveValue method as

```
sysf = { D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] +  D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] + 
     D[f[x, y], x, y] == 
       NeumannValue[1, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, y == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[0, y == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, x == 1]};

solf = NDSolveValue[sysf,  
   f , {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]];


fplot = ContourPlot[
   Abs[solf[x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y,  Abs[f]},  PlotLabel -> "f", 
   ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];
GraphicsRow[{fplot}]
```

[image]

I get no warnings or errors, but the result is clearly incorrect. The gradient normal on the boundaries $y=0$ and $y=1$ are finite, and in conflict with my enforced boundary conditions.

Apparently, NDSolveValue has ignored my NeumannValue boundary conditions, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: The solution looks correct to me. Maybe you have  miss understand what a NeumannValue does; did you have a look at the 'Details' section on the ref page? Also note that the Neumann 0 values at y==0 or y==1 can be left out, as a Neumann 0 is the implicit default value.

Comment: Did you check which `NeumannValue` belong to your pde-problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pde problem possesses the following `NeumannValue`'s

```
{state} =NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{ 
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]  + D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] +D[f[x, y], x, y]  ==NeumannValue[1, x == 0]  , 
DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, x == 1] }, 
f, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[]];

NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE[state]
```

$\left\{\nabla _{\{x,y\}}\cdot \left(-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\nabla _{\{x,y\}}f(x,y)\right)\right\}$

Last formula (normal brakets) shows the flux. Thus the NeumannValue at x==0 is
  `Derivative[1, 0][solf][0, y] + 1/2 Derivative[0, 1][solf][0, y]`

```
Plot[  Derivative[1, 0][solf][0, y] + 1/2 Derivative[0, 1][solf][0, y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0.9, 1.1} ]
```

[image]

Plot shows `NeumannValue[1,x==0]` is quite good fullfilled.